# Strange Error From Hive SQL in Hue

Tags: sql, hive, hue

I'm running SQL queries using Hive through Hue. I'm been receiving this error when running full outer join queries. I've slowly simplified to the most basic query I can think of to try to identify where the problem is. I'm down to the most basic possibility and am still receiving the error. If anyone has any suggestions or thoughts, they would be greatly appreciated. The query and error are below.

```
select * from tbl1
Full Outer Join tbl2 on tble1.clm = tble2.clm1;
```

> Error in sasl_decode (-1) SASL(-1): generic failure: Unable to find a callback: 32775 (code THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException('Error in sasl_decode (-1) SASL(-1): generic failure: Unable to find a callback: 32775',)